# Are the tenses in this sentence mixed, one present continuous and one present simple?

Tags: present-continuous

Are the tenses in this sentence mixed with the beginning being present continuous for a new habit which will have an end, and the end being present simple for a permanent state?

> she is now working at home 2 days per week, the other days of the week she works at her office as usual

I would like to know if present simple for the other days of the week is possible because it has not changed, i.e. it is a permanent state.

Comment: Yes, the sentence seems fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

The verb tense is fine. But the sentence is actually two statements and should be divided with a period (not a comma):

"She is now working at home 2 days per week. The other days of the week she works at her office as usual."

Comment: Or a semicolon. Welcome - please take the [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "the other days of the week she works at her office as usual" is perfectly correct and natural, it implies an ongoing stable condition, not expect4ed to change.

It could be rewritten to use "working" for example

> She is now working at home 2 days per week; she is working at her office on the other days of the week she works at as usual.

This emphasizes the current state of things, and does not convey as much of an impression of stability, but the difference is quite subtle, and the essential meaning is the same.

Personally I would prefer "two days a week" or more formally "two days every week" to "two days per week", this use of "per" doesn't seem quite natural to me, but it is certainly not wrong., this is really a matter of style.

As written, the sentence could be read to imply that she is  working every day: two days at home and the other five at her office. I don't think that is what is intended, but the use of "other days of the week" somewhat implies that. This imp0lication could be avoided by saying "the other three days" or "the other work days" or some similar qualification; perhaps this is slightly pedantic.